# PHP explode string into array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm using PHP and I need to explode a string into an array. The issue is that there are commas where I don't need to explode.

Here is my string:

```
123456,ABC1234,Realtor,123-123-1234,"United States (+1)",Cell,,,,Home,,"MLS and BOARD",RE,Agent,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Hardi Type Siding","Central Air",,"One,Gas",Detached,,,"Forced Air,Heat Pump,Propane"
```

I don't want to split where there's a comma in the string surrounded by quotes. For example, I don't want to split "Forced Air,Heat Pump,Propane".

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). It parses a string as a line from a CSV file, including processing quotes to protect commas inside a field.

And if you're actually reading this from a CSV file, you could use `fgetcsv()` to do both the read and parse in one step.